# Why this solution works?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two integers: **n** and **m** and n is divisible by 2m, I have to write down the first n natural numbers in the following form.

At first first m integers are taken and their sign negative is made negative,

then next m integers are taken and their sign is made positive,

the next m integers should have negative signs and continue this procedure until all the n integers have been assigned a sign. For example, let n be 12 and m be 3. Then we have

**-1 -2 -3 +4 +5 +6 -7 -8 -9 +10 +11 +12**

If n = 4 and m = 1, then we have

**-1 +2 -3 +4**

Now,given n and m I need to find the sum.

The solution to this problem is $$m*n/2$$ . But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that n=2m. Then:

$$(-1-2-\cdots-m)+((m+1)+(m+2)+\cdots+(2m))=(m+1-1)+(m+2-2)+\cdots+(2m-m)=m+\cdots+m \text(m \ times)=m^2$$.

Then, given that $2m$ divides $n$, this process can be done separating the whole sum as $n/2m$ sums, each of which result to be $m^2$. Then the whole sum is:

$$m^2+\cdots+m^2 (n/2m \ times)=m^2*n/2m=m*n/2$$

For example, if $n=12$ and $m=3$ then

$$-1-2-3+4+5+6-7-8-9+10+11+12=((4-1)+(5-2)+(6-3))+((10-7)+(11-8)+(12-9))=(3+3+3)+(3+3+3)=3^2+3^2=3^2*2=3^2*12/(2*3)=3*12/2$$